# Vectorize and iterrow operation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a dataframe in pandas that I ordered by timestamp.

I want to do this pseudo-code:

```
foreach line in dataframe:  
__x = True  
__foreach number in list:
____if line['col1']<number:  
______x = False  
__if x ==True:
____list.append(line['col1'])
```

Considering that it's necessary to iterate in order, is there a way to vectorize that (iterrow is to slow)?

Comment: What is `list` in your code? How do you expect to parallelize that code if `list` is updated independently by each row? Is `col1` the only column in the dataframe that you care about?

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a variable name, because it's a reserved word in Python.

Comment: How is this not just `np.where(df['col1'] < number, False, True)` (or simplified to `~df['col1'] < number)`) followed by `df['col1'][df['result_column']]`?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 list is a list of float. It real name is not 'list'. It's juste to simplify the pseudo-code. col1 is not the only column in the dataframe that I care about. column2 is also important. 
The problem is the iteration in dataframe. I wan't to add to the list only the consecutives lines that agreed with the condition.

Comment: Do you want your `list` to be updated while iterating through the rows in the dataframes? That's what you code is showing right now.

Comment: Yes exactly @stackoverflowuser2010

Comment: What is the desired output of your code? Is it the accumulated list? Or is it the smallest / biggest value in the list?